# How to find all users in active directory for a given set of groups

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I want to pull user information who are a part of any of the groups provided as an input.(lets say i want to pull user information along with the group name, only for the users who belongs to either groups(a, b,c,d,e) where a, b ,c,d,e are group names. How can I acheive this using C# and powershell.

Answer (score 1):

With PowerShell using Get-ADUser (from the AD Tools module):
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx
With an ldapFilter (&((objectclass=user)(|(memberOf=DnGroupA)(memberOf=DnGroupB)...))

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use `Get-ADGroupMember` from the Active Directory Cmdlets. You can pipe your list of group names into it and it will output the group members.

To get all the members of groups I am in:

```
Get-ADUser 'hsimah' -Properties memberOf | Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberOf | Get-ADGroupMember
```

To get group member names by group name or distinguished name:

```
'All Staff','CN=Everyone,OU=Australia,DC=global,DC=company,DC=com' | Get-AdGroupMember | Select-Object name
```